# Qlik - Building a dynamic view

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have a SQL query that creates a table, and every month 2 new columns will be added for that table related to the current month.

I have tried without success to set up a flat table (visual) in Qlik that will automatically expand every month to include these table. Is there a way to do this, and i so please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at [CrossTable](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/May2022/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Scripting/ScriptPrefixes/crosstable.htm) prefix.

This prefix allows a wide table to be converted to a long table.

So if we have data like this:

[image: Raw data]

After running the following script:

```
CrossTable:
CrossTable(Month, Sales)
LOAD Item, 
     [2022-10], 
     [2022-11], 
     [2022-12], 
     [2023-01], 
     [2023-02], 
     [2023-03], 
     [2023-04]
FROM
[C:\Users\User1\Documents\SO_75447715.xlsx]
(ooxml, embedded labels, table is Sheet1);
```

The final data will looks like below. As you can see there are only 3 columns. All xls month columns (after `Item`) are now collapsed under one field - `Month` and all the values are collapsed under `Sales` column.

[image: Data view]

Having the data in this format then allows creating "normal" charts with adding `Month` column as dimension and use `sum(Sales)` as an expression.

[image: Charts]

P.S. If you dont want to manage the new columns being added then the script can be:

```
CrossTable(Month, Sales)
LOAD 
  Item, 
  *
FROM
...
```